# How to Insert Select from last table auto increment Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as shown here:

[image]

I need to insert some data by a stored procedure as below code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeviceInvoiceInsert]
    @dt AS DeviceInvoiceArray READONLY
AS
    DECLARE @customerDeviceId BIGINT
    DECLARE @customerId BIGINT
    DECLARE @filterChangeDate DATE
BEGIN
    SET @customerId = (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerId FROM @dt 
                       WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL)
    SET @filterChangeDate = (SELECT TOP 1 filterChangeDate FROM @dt)

    INSERT INTO CustomerDevice (customerId, deviceId, deviceBuyDate, devicePrice)
        SELECT customerId, deviceId, deviceBuyDate, devicePrice 
        FROM @dt 
        WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL

    SET @customerDeviceId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO FilterChange (customerId, filterId, customerDeviceId, filterChangeDate)
        SELECT @customerId, dt.filterId, @customerDeviceId, @filterChangeDate 
        FROM @dt AS dt
END
```

The problem is that when the procedure wants to insert data into the `FilterChange` table, the `@customerDeviceId` always has the last IDENTITY Id.

How can I figure out this problem?

**Update**
Thanks for `@T N` answer but his solution is just to insert one filter per device, so in my case, there can be many filters per device

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns a scalar value, and (yes) it is documented to return the *last* `IDENTITY` value generated in that scope; what value are you actually expected from `SCOPE_IDENTITY`? The first value? The second? An arbitrary one? If you want to get *all* the `IDENTITY` values, you'll need to use an `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Just to add on to @larnu using an OUTPUT is the best way to capture the identity value(s) for passing them on to foreign key values in subsequent inserts in other tables. Trying to manage that yourself can result in data integrity issues.

Comment: Why do you need to store `customerId` redundantly in `FilterChange`? Is it ever going to be different than what is in `CustomerDevice` for the same `customerDeviceId`?

Comment: Also, [cross-site dupe here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/322726/1186), with a questionable (maybe AI?) answer...

Comment: It's not AI, I just can't find my answer and repeat it on another forum.  @TN's answer is not correct because In my case I have many filters per device and its solution is just back one filter per device which I could solve before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@TN`, his solution is just to insert one filter per device, so in my case, there can be many filters per device, So I just manipulate the last part to solve the problem. Also the corrected @dt value is like this:
[image]
As you can see, there are many filters per device, and All customers are the same because per invoice belongs to one customer so I had to mark the rest repetitive devices with `null` to group filters per device.

Here is the corrected code, Thanks by @tn:

```
    -- Example showing MERGE (instead of INSERT) to capture a combination of
-- source and inserted data in an OUTPUT clause.

CREATE TABLE CustomerDevice (
    customerDeviceId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    customerId INT,
    deviceId INT,
    deviceBuyDate DATE,
    devicePrice NUMERIC(19,4)
)
CREATE TABLE FilterChange (
    customerId INT,
    filterId INT,
    customerDeviceId INT, 
    filterChangeDate DATE
)

DECLARE @dt TABLE (
    customerId INT,
    deviceId INT,
    deviceBuyDate DATE,
    devicePrice NUMERIC(19,4),
    filterId INT,
    filterChangeDate DATE
)
INSERT @dt
VALUES
    (3, 1, '2023-01-01', 111.11, 1, '2023-02-01'),
    (NULL, 1, '2023-01-02', 222.22, 2, '2023-02-02'),
    (NULL, 1, '2023-01-03', 333.33, 3, '2023-02-03'),
    (NULL, 1, '2023-01-03', 333.33, 4, '2023-02-03'),
    (3, 2, '2023-01-04', 333.33, 1, '2023-02-04'),
    (NULL, 2, '2023-01-04', 333.33, 2, '2023-02-04'),
    (NULL, 2, '2023-01-04', 333.33, 3, '2023-02-04'),
    (NULL, 2, '2023-01-04', 333.33, 4, '2023-02-04')

-- Procedure body

    DECLARE @customerId BIGINT

    SET @customerId = (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerId FROM @dt WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL)
  
   DECLARE @FilterChangeData TABLE (
        customerId INT,
        deviceId INT,
        filterId INT,
        customerDeviceId INT,
        filterChangeDate DATETIME
    )

    MERGE CustomerDevice AS TGT
    USING (SELECT * FROM @dt WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL) AS SRC
        ON 1 = 0 -- Never match
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (customerId, deviceId, deviceBuyDate, devicePrice)
        VALUES (SRC.customerId, SRC.deviceId, SRC.deviceBuyDate, SRC.devicePrice) 
        OUTPUT SRC.customerId,SRC.deviceId, SRC.filterId, INSERTED.customerDeviceId, SRC.filterChangeDate
            INTO @FilterChangeData;

   INSERT INTO FilterChange (customerId, filterId, customerDeviceId, filterChangeDate)
        SELECT @customerId, dt.filterId, fcd.customerDeviceId, dt.filterChangeDate 
        FROM @dt AS dt INNER JOIN @FilterChangeData AS fcd
        ON fcd.deviceId = dt.deviceId


-- End procedure body
      
SELECT * FROM @dt
SELECT * FROM CustomerDevice
SELECT * FROM FilterChange
```

Result show in, [https://dbfiddle.uk/yf7z_wqr][2]

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, using the `OUTPUT` clause is the best way to capture inserted IDENTITY or other implicitly assigned values.  However, you also need to correlate this data with other values from your source table. As far as I know, this cannot be done using a regular `INSERT` statement, which only allows you to capture data from the target table via the `INSERTED` pseudo-table.

I am assuming that none of the explicitly inserted values in the first target table can be used to reliably uniquely identify the source record.

A workaround is to use the `MERGE` statement to perform the insert. The `OUTPUT` clause may then be used to capture a combination of source and inserted target data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeviceInvoiceInsert]
    @dt AS DeviceInvoiceArray READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- Temp table to receive captured data from output clause
    DECLARE @FilterChangeData TABLE (
        customerId INT,
        filterId INT,
        customerDeviceId INT,
        filterChangeDate DATETIME2
    )

    -- Merge is used instead of a plain INSERT so that we can capture
    -- a combination of source and inserted data
    MERGE CustomerDevice AS TGT
    USING (SELECT * FROM @dt WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL) AS SRC
        ON 1 = 0 -- Never match
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (customerId, deviceId, deviceBuyDate, devicePrice)
        VALUES (SRC.customerId, SRC.deviceId, SRC.deviceBuyDate, SRC.devicePrice) 
        OUTPUT SRC.customerId, SRC.filterId, INSERTED.customerDeviceId, SRC.filterChangeDate
            INTO @FilterChangeData
    ;

    INSERT INTO FilterChange (customerId, filterId, customerDeviceId, filterChangeDate)
        SELECT customerId, filterId, customerDeviceId, filterChangeDate 
        FROM @FilterChangeData
END
```

Given the following @dt source data:

| customerId | deviceId | deviceBuyDate | devicePrice | filterId | filterChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 111 | 2023-01-01 | 111.1100 | 1111 | 2023-02-01 |
| 22 | 222 | 2023-01-02 | 222.2200 | 2222 | 2023-02-02 |
| 33 | 333 | 2023-01-03 | 333.3300 | 3333 | 2023-02-03 |
| 11 | 222 | 2023-01-04 | 333.3300 | 1111 | 2023-02-04 |

The following is inserted into CustomerDevice:

| customerDeviceId | customerId | deviceId | deviceBuyDate | devicePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | 2023-01-01 | 111.1100 |
| 2 | 22 | 222 | 2023-01-02 | 222.2200 |
| 3 | 33 | 333 | 2023-01-03 | 333.3300 |
| 4 | 11 | 222 | 2023-01-04 | 333.3300 |

The following is inserted into FilterChange:

| customerId | filterId | customerDeviceId | filterChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1111 | 1 | 2023-02-01 |
| 22 | 2222 | 2 | 2023-02-02 |
| 33 | 3333 | 3 | 2023-02-03 |
| 11 | 1111 | 4 | 2023-02-04 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KvpadeC7).

Comment: For the specific scenario above, the `OUTPUT` clause can be changed to direct the captured values directly into the `FilterChange` table, eliminating the need for a temporary table and separate insert. (My preference, however, is to follow the original pattern with separate statements for each insert.)

Comment: @T_N Could breaking into 2 INSERTs cause integrity issues if there is an error?

Comment: It the FilterChange insert fails and the entire operation is not wrapped in a transaction, it could leave the results of the CustomerDevice insert (merge) in place. I do not know whether or not this would still occur if OUTPUT from the merge was directed directly into the FilterChange table. The MERGE statement has had issues with atomicity identified in the past, but this might be limited to separate processing of "matched", "not matched by source" and "not matched by target" cases. If integrity and consistency are important, it's best to use a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your solution is just to insert one filter per device so in my case there can be many filters per device

Comment: Well, your original post showed code that would insert N records into `CustomerDevice` and N records into `FilterChange`, where N was the number of records passed in as `@dt`. Your only question appeared to be how to capture multiple distinct customerDeviceId values from the first insert to use in the second insert. That is what I took the time to answer. Now it appears your scenario is different. I suggest you go back and revisit your question, **be more specific about your requirements**, and **provide both sample `@dt` data and expected `CustomerDevice` and `FilterChange` results**.

Comment: Okay. I now see that your original code may insert `FilterChange` rows for those `@dt` rows having a NULL `CustomerId`. But it is unclear how you would expect to correlate those rows with `customerDeviceId` values when no corresponding `CustomerDevice` rows were inserted. My suggestion that you clarify your requirements and provide sample source and result data stands.