# How can I do an insert for two tables at the same time using SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables that I need to populate with 100 rows from a remote linked database.

The first table is easy, because I can just do a simple INSERT from a SELECT.

However, I also need to populate a second table, using the cameraId (which is automatically generated) from the first table.

But when I try to run the queries, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'SCOPE_IDENTITY()'

Code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.camera
(
    cameraId,     --AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED IDENTITY SEED VALUE
    productName,
    productDesc,
    productCode
)
SELECT CAMERA_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT_CODE
FROM [SQL_CANADA].[BASE].[dbo].PRODUCT
WHERE ORIGIN_ID = 19327761

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

INSERT INTO dbo.cameraLense
(
    lenseId,
    cameraId,      --SCOPE_IDENTITY() ??
    type,
    materialId,
    isCurrentYear,
    modelNumber
)
SELECT LENSE_ID, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), LENSE_TYPE, MATERIAL_ID, IS_CURRENT_YEAR, MODEL_NUMBER
FROM [SQL_CANADA].[BASE].[dbo].PRODUCT
WHERE ORIGIN_ID = 19327761
```

Is there anything that I could do to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `watifor` for? Is there only one lens per camera? Otherwise how are you avoiding inserting multiple cameras for each camera / lens combo? Also, I [can't reproduce your syntax error](https://dbfiddle.uk/cvtnNNPk) so I don't think the code you've shown is the code you're running

Comment: You generally can't insert into two tables "at the same time" unless you can use an `OUTPUT` clause. But this would mean all of the info for the second table needs to be derivable from variables or the affected columns in the first table. The code you've posted doesn't seem like this is possible, but also I don't think the code you've posted is real, because how can a camera and its lenses be derived from the exact same rows in `Product`?

Comment: Also If `dbo.Camera.CameraId` was an Identity you would not include it in your select / insert, so this makes little sense. Please add some clarity with sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is not the magic you want it to be, and shouldn't really be used. Instead, use the `OUTPUT` clause with your insert.

```
/* Demo objects */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Cameras; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CameraLenses;
CREATE TABLE #Cameras (CameraID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ProductName NVARCHAR(50), ProductDesc NVARCHAR(200), ProductCode NVARCHAR(6));
CREATE TABLE #CameraLenses (LensID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CameraID BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #Cameras (CameraID), LensType NVARCHAR(20), MaterialID BIGINT, IsCurrentYear BIT, ModelNumber NVARCHAR(10));
```

There's no point creating a FK on a temp table, expect for illustration, you can ignore the warning you get back during the insert.

```
DECLARE @Outputs TABLE (InsertedIdent BIGINT, InsertedProductCode NVARCHAR(6));
INSERT INTO #Cameras (ProductName, ProductDesc, ProductCode) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.CameraID, INSERTED.ProductCode INTO @Outputs
SELECT ProductName, ProductDesc, ProductCode
  FROM (
        SELECT 'UberCam' AS ProductName, 'Fine German craftsmanship' AS ProductDesc, 'UBER01' AS ProductCode
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'AffreuseCam', 'Shoddy French knock-off', 'AFFR01'
        /* you can substitute this for a UDTT to pass in a table of cameras */
       ) a;

INSERT INTO #CameraLenses (CameraID, LensType, MaterialID, IsCurrentYear, ModelNumber) 
SELECT o.InsertedIdent, Type, MaterialID, IsCurrentYear, ModelNumber
  FROM (
        SELECT 'Digital' AS Type, 1 AS MaterialID, 1 AS IsCurrentYear, 'UBERLENS01' AS ModelNumber, 'UBER01' AS CameraProductCode
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Flash Bulb', 2, 0, 'AFFRLEBS01', 'AFFR01'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Microscope', 2, 0, 'UBERLENS02', 'UBER01'
        /* you can substitute this for a UDTT to pass in a table of camera lenses */
       ) a
  INNER JOIN @Outputs o
    ON a.CameraProductCode = o.InsertedProductCode;

SELECT c.CameraID, c.ProductName, c.ProductDesc, c.ProductCode, cl.LensID, cl.CameraID, cl.LensType, cl.MaterialID, cl.IsCurrentYear, cl.ModelNumber
  FROM #Cameras c
    INNER JOIN #CameraLenses cl
      ON c.CameraID = cl.CameraID;
```

There's a few things going on here, so let's walk through it.
First, we're declaring a table variable which we will use to hold pairs of the newly generated identity column, and something we already know about to link back to it.

Then we do an insert into the `#Cameras` table. Nestled in there between the `INSERT` and `SELECT is the` OUTPUT`. All we're doing here is asking for the values from the pseudo table` INSERTED` to be stuffed into it.

Next we do the insert into the `#Lenses` table. This time we have the data in our table variable, so we're able to join to it and collect the values we just inserted for `#Cameras` and reference them during our insert.

Finally, we do a quick select on the tables we just inserted into to review what happened.

| CameraID | ProductName | ProductDesc | ProductCode | LensID | CameraID | LensType | MaterialID | IsCurrentYear | ModelNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UberCam | Fine German craftsmanship | UBER01 | 1 | 1 | Digital | 1 | 1 | UBERLENS01 |
| 2 | AffreuseCam | Shoddy French knock-off | AFFR01 | 2 | 2 | Flash Bulb | 2 | 0 | AFFRLEBS01 |
| 1 | UberCam | Fine German craftsmanship | UBER01 | 3 | 1 | Microscope | 2 | 0 | UBERLENS02 |

Going further with this, you could also use User Defined Table Types to pass in the values you're going to insert, but they do come with a warning. Essentially you can create a `UDTT` to pass in a table. You define the table structure in the UDTT create, and then you can use it as if it were any other data type:

```
DECLARE @table NewInvoiceTable;
INSERT INTO @table (CustomerID, EmployeeID ...) VALUES
(1, 2 ...),(2, 2 ...);
```

You can only define them as parameters using the `READONLY` tag:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCustomers @NewCustomers NewCustomerTable READONLY...
```

You cannot drop a `UDTT` while something is referencing it, and you cannot `ALTER TYPE` at all. This makes it a pain if you need to change them.

Comment: As a variation of the above, if the data inserted into the first table does not uniquely identify the source row (for example if `ProductCode` is not unique), the `MERGE` statement can be used instead of `INSERT` with the advantage that the `OUTPUT` clause can capture a combination of source and inserted data. For example, if the `PRODUCT` table had a unique `ProductId`, you can capture it together with the assigned `CameraId` for use in matching up data for the second insert. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277743/#75278390) for a similar use case.