# id obtained through output in an insert query needs to be passed to another insertquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec, sql-insert

Until this line

```
EXEC sp_executesql @InsertQuery, N'@product_id BIGINT OUTPUT', @product_id OUTPUT
```

I managed to obtain the product_id correctly, the problem is when inserting in the @InsertQuery2, it inserts product_id = NULL

```
DECLARE @InsertQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @InsertQuery = '
        INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@bdEmpresa) + '.dbo.Producto (
            producto_codigo,
            producto_codigoanterior,
            producto_status
        )
        OUTPUT INSERTED.producto_id
        SELECT 
            producto_codigo,
            producto_codigoanterior,
            producto_status
        FROM #TempProducto'

    -- Ejecutar la consulta de inserción y capturar el producto_id generado
    EXEC sp_executesql @InsertQuery, N'@producto_id BIGINT OUTPUT', @producto_id OUTPUT

    -- Insertar datos de proveedores en la tabla de la base de datos de la empresa
    DECLARE @InsertQuery2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @InsertQuery2 = '
        INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@bdEmpresa) + '.dbo.ProductoProveedor (
            producto_id,
            proveedor_ruc,
            proveedor_dscto
        )
        SELECT 
            @producto_id,
            proveedor_ruc,
            proveedor_dscto
        FROM #TempProveedores'

    -- Ejecutar la consulta de inserción
    EXEC sp_executesql @InsertQuery2, N'@producto_id BIGINT', @producto_id
```

I need to pass the id obtained after registration in the Product table to @InsertQuery2 since I need to insert it there too

Comment: `OUTPUT INSERTED.producto_id` outputs as a query, not into a parameter.

Comment: Why not save some kittens and combine them into one dynamic query

Comment: Unfortunately, `OUTPUT` is misleadingly overloaded. In that context, it doesn't `OUTPUT`, it `SELECT`s.

Comment: (And other possible keywords were taken too, like `RETURN`.)

Comment: Also, to avoid having to concatenate database name into the dynamic SQL, you can use `DECLARE @exec nvarchar(512); SET @exec = CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@bdEmpresa), N'.sys.sp_executesql'); ... EXEC @exec @InsertQuery, ...;` - this can make your dynamic SQL a little easier to read/manage.

Comment: Can #TempProducto have more than one row? If so, you will also need a way to associate the generated identity values back to the original source table row. The techniques used depends on whether or not the source contains a unique value column that is also inserted in the first target table. If so, a simple join may be used. If not, the solution is a bit more complicated and involves using a MERGE instead of an INSERT to capture a combination of source and inserted column values. that can then feed the second insert. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277743#75278390).

Answer (score 2):

`OUTPUT` returns a whole resultset. To capture and reuse it in another query you need to add `INTO someTable`.

Also, instead of injecting the database name, you can construct a variable containing `SomeDb.sys.sp_executesql` and then do `EXEC @proc`

```sql
DECLARE @InsertQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

DECLARE @ids TABLE (id bigint NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.Producto (
    producto_codigo,
    producto_codigoanterior,
    producto_status
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.producto_id
INTO @ids (id)
SELECT 
    producto_codigo,
    producto_codigoanterior,
    producto_status
FROM #TempProducto;

INSERT INTO dbo.ProductoProveedor (
    producto_id,
    proveedor_ruc,
    proveedor_dscto
)
SELECT 
    i.id,
    p.proveedor_ruc,
    p.proveedor_dscto
FROM #TempProveedores p
CROSS JOIN @ids AS i;    -- shouldn''t this have some kind of join condition
';

DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@bdEmpresa) + '.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @proc @InsertQuery;
```

If you are using temp tables just to pass data between procedures then you should consider Table Types and Table Valued Parameters, as these are better designed to do that.